# CakePHP 2.6 Access Controller Object within a Component

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.6

I've got a Component that is used by many controllers, and I was wondering if there is a way to access the Controller object from the Component without having to pass it into the Component.

For example I'm currently passing in a reference to the controller into MyAuthComponent:

```
$this->Auth->isAuthenticated($this);
```

But, I'd rather be able to invoke this without having to pass the references if possible.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Component callbacks receive controller instance as a parameter. So using your component's `startup()` callback save the reference to component property and you can then use that in other methods of your component. Check the manual/api for the list of arguments `startup()` receives.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code example for @ADmad answere

```
class AuthComponent extends Component {    
    var $controller = null;
         /**
         * Startup component
         *
         * @param object $controller Instantiating controller
         * @access public
         */ 
        public function startup(Controller $controller) {        
            $this->controller = $controller;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per cakephp3.x guidelines using registry you can access current controller from within component.

```
$controller = $this->_registry->getController();
```

and you can access controller in any component callback methods using event objects mentioned below.

```
$controller = $event->getSubject();
```